# Variance of empirical mean squared error of binomial distribution

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution

Given $m$ binomially distributed samples $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$. Let $\hat{p}_i=X_i/n$ be the corresponding estimates for $p$. The empirical mean squared error is given by $Z= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (\hat{p}_i-p)^2$. I am looking for the expected value and the variance of $Z$. $E(Z) = p(1-p)/n$ follows directly from the variance of the binomial distribution. Is there a simple way to also get $\text{Var(Z)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd call it "simple", but it's nevertheless fairly straightforward:
\begin{align}
E\left(Z^2\right)&=\frac{1}{m^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^mE\left(\left(\hat{p}_i-p\right)^4\right)+2\sum_{i=2}^m\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} E\left(\left(\hat{p}_i-p\right)^2\left(\hat{p}_j-p\right)^2\right)\right)\\
&= \frac{\mu_4}{mn^4}+\frac{(m-1)p^2(1-p)^2}{mn^2}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ \mu_4=E\left(\left(X_i-np\right)^4\right)\ $ is the $\ 4$-th central moment of $\ X_i\ $—which Wolfram Mathworld [gives](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialDistribution.html) as $\ \mu_4=3n(n-2)p^2(1-p)^2 + np(1-p)\ $.  Therefore:
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(Z)&=E\left(Z^2\right)-E(Z)^2\\
&= \frac{\mu_4}{mn^4}+\frac{(m-1)p^2(1-p)^2}{mn^2}-\frac{p^2(1-p)^2}{n^2}\\
&= \frac{\mu_4}{mn^4}-\frac{p^2(1-p)^2}{mn^2}\\
&=\frac{2(n-3)p^2(1-p)^2+p(1-p)}{mn^3}
\end{align}

Comment: @ lonza-leggiera why did use double sum for $E(Z^2)$ ?

Comment: $$
Z=\frac{1}{m}\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\big(\hat{p}_i-p\big)^2=\frac{1}{m}\sum_\limits{j=1}^m\big(\hat{p_j}-p\big)^2\ .
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
Z^2&=\Big(\frac{1}{m}\sum_\limits{i=1}^m\big(\hat{p}_i-p\big)^2\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{m}\sum_\limits{j=1}^m\big(\hat{p_j}-p\big)^2\Big)\\
&=\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m\big(\hat{p}_i-p\big)^2\big(\hat{p_j}-p\big)^2
\end{align}